# InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.amazonaws.management:type=AwsSdkMetrics

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm getting below error while instantiation AwsClient

```
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) 09:39:29.398 [default task-20] DEBUG com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans - Failed to register mbean com.amazonaws.management:type=AwsSdkMetrics
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.amazonaws.management:type=AwsSdkMetrics
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,399 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.registerMBean(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:1527)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.registerMBean(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:871)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:52)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:398)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:359)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<clinit>(AmazonS3Client.java:367)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,400 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:28)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.hpp.clinics.fileupload.AwsS3FileUpload.generateSignedUrl(AwsS3FileUpload.java:362)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at com.tcs.hpp.clinics.resource.HPPClinicOfflineService.getSignedUrl(HPPClinicOfflineService.java:984)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,401 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,402 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,403 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2018-12-22 09:39:29,405 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
```

The code is below:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
                    .build();
```

This error is occurring only in the server. When I try this on my local computer, it works fine. We are having a single application deployed on our server. So, it is not happening because of multiple applications being deployed on same server.

What could be the issue? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: are you logging requests/responses to CloudWatch somewhere in your application?

Comment: no we are not logging

Comment: can you post your pom file /build file ?

Comment: Is that related? Because on my local it is working fine.